# What are all the options of the treeview function?

Tags: jquery

What are all the possible options and their values for the `treeview` function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [TreeViewJs](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-treeview/blob/master/jquery.treeview.js). It is pretty well documented.
Some of the settings/ options are

```
cookieId - string(can be any valid js string, default - "treeview" ),
toggle   - bool (True/False),
animated - bool (True/False),
unique   - bool (True/False),
prerendered - bool (True/False),
collapsed -  bool (True/False),
persist - string ('cookie' / 'location')
control - jquery element
```

Comment: What do these options mean ?

Comment: the names tell all about what they are being used for :)